# "Cannot read property of undefined" when calling a components view model function from outside the component in Aurelia w/ TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

It was my understanding that with view-model.ref I could access the viewmodel of the component from outside the component and call it's functions.

Below code results in Cannot read property 'LoadForAdditionalLocations' of undefined

**Component to Import**

```
export class UserLocationSelector {
    public LoadForAdditionalLocations(reportLogin:string, addLocationsLogin:string){
        ///do stuff
    }
}
```

**Page that component is on (TS file)**

```
export class AddLocation{
    attached(){
        this.UserLocationSelector.LoadForAdditionalLocations("user1","user2");
    }
}
```

**Page that component is on (htmlfile)**

```
<template>
    <require from='user-location-selector'></require>
    <div>
         <user-location-selector view-model.ref="UserLocationSelector"></user-location-selector>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you pass to the ref attribute becomes a property on your VM, so it must be accessed using `this.`. For this reason, it's recommended you follow JavaScript naming conventions.

**Component to Import**

```
export class UserLocationSelector {
    public loadForAdditionalLocations(reportLogin:string, addLocationsLogin:string){
        ///do stuff
    }
}
```

**Page that component is on (TS file)**

```
export class AddLocation{
    userLocationSelector;

    attached(){
        this.userLocationSelector.loadForAdditionalLocations("user1","user2");
    }
}
```

**Page that component is on (htmlfile)**

```
<template>
    <require from='user-location-selector'></require>
    <div>
         <user-location-selector view-model.ref="userLocationSelector"></user-location-selector>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's an example gist: https://gist.run/?id=96774bc2d99de0b421880b8977f081d4

Comment: I actually was using this.UserLocationSelector and results in same error.

Comment: I've added an example gist

Comment: I can get it to work using javascript. Not in TypeScript though.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind creating a repro from one of our typescript skeletons, I'll try to help you out further.

Comment: Don't you want the name of the actual custom element like `user-location-selector.ref`? I didn't realise you could use `view-model.ref`

Comment: @SamuelElrod I'm not sure where your message with a repro went, but I pulled it down and ran it without issue, once I added `uls;` as a property in the `Welcome` class. Here's a screengrab: http://i.imgur.com/bSgQlWk.jpg

Comment: @Charleh, that ended up working; can you post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @SamuelElrod my answer is correct. `view-model.ref` is perfectly valid and works. And thus my answer is correct. I'd appreciate if you would accept my answer.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I created a new project and your answer does indeed work. Something must be going on in my actual dev project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. could it be a typo in your view code, possibly?

Comment: @AshleyGrant, found the problem. In my actual code I was calling it from activate instead of attached.

Comment: that'll do it. I make that mistake somewhat often

Comment: I assume the view model variant only refs the primary behaviour (e.g. Custom element and not any custom attributes), not gonna argue with aurelia team members btw :)